# Why do I keep getting extra characters at the end of my string?

Tags: c, string

I have the string, "helLo, wORld!" and I want my program to change it to "Hello, World!". My program works, the characters are changed correctly, but I keep getting extra characters after the exclamation mark. What could I be doing wrong?

```
void normalize_case(char str[], char result[])
{
   if (islower(str[0]) == 1)
   {
      result[0] = toupper(str[0]);
   }

   for (int i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      if (isupper(str[i]) == 1)
      {
         result[i] = tolower(str[i]);
      }

      else if (islower(str[i]) == 1)
      {
         result[i] = str[i];
      }

      if (islower(str[i]) == 0 && isupper(str[i]) == 0)
      {
         result[i] = str[i];
      }

      if (str[i] == ' ')
      {
         result[i] = str[i];
      }

      if (str[i - 1] == ' ' && islower(str[i]) == 1)
      {
         result[i] = toupper(str[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Extra characters like what?

Comment: As far as I can tell you are not null terminating `result`.

Comment: It's a mixture of special characters like question marks and letters. I'm thinking, could it be because I didn't put '\0' at the end? I don't remember exactly how to do this, but when I asked my instructor, he said to add '\0' at the end of the program...:/

Comment: `if (isupper(str[i]) == 1)` => `if (isupper(str[i]))`

Comment: `if (islower(str[i]) == 0 && isupper(str[i]) == 0)` - if it's not lower case and it's not upper case then what is it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Extra random-ish characters at the end of a string usually means you've forgotten to null-terminate (`'\0'`) your string.  Your loop copies everything up to, but not including, the terminal null into the result.

Add `result[i] = '\0';` after the loop before you return.

Normally, you treat the `isxxxx()` functions (macros) as returning a boolean condition, and you'd ensure that you only have one of the chain of conditions executed.  You'd do that with more careful use of `else` clauses. Your code actually copies `str[i]` multiple times if it is a blank. In fact, I think you can compress your loop to:

```
int i;

for (i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
   if (isupper(str[i]))
       result[i] = tolower(str[i]);
   else if (str[i - 1] == ' ' && islower(str[i]))
       result[i] = toupper(str[i]);
   else
       result[i] = str[i];
}
result[i] = '\0';
```

> If I put `result[i]` outside of the for loop, won't the compiler complain about `i`?

Yes, it will.  In this context, you need `i` defined outside the loop control, because you need the value after the loop.  See the amended code above.

You might also note that your pre-loop code quietly skips the first character of the string if it is not lower-case, leaving garbage as the first character of the result.  You should really write:

```
result[0] = toupper(str[0]);
```

so that `result[0]` is always set.

Comment: If I put result[i] outside of the for loop, won't the compiler complain about i?

Answer (score 2):

You are not null terminating `result` so when you print it out it will keep going until a null is found. If you move the declaration of `i` to before the `for` loop:

```
int i ;
for ( i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

you can add:

```
result[i] = '\0' ;
```

after the `for` loop, this is assuming `result` is large enough.

Comment: Oh! I see, would I just say, return '\0' at the outside of the for loop before the end? I'm a bit confused on how to write this. :(

Comment: Thanks for the help! :) I've got it now. :D

Answer (score 1):

You should add a statement `result[i] = '\0'` at the end of the loop because in the C language, the string array should end with a special character '\0', which tells the compiler "this is the end of the string".

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of simplifying your code as a lot of the checks you do are unnecessary. The others have already explained some basic points to keep in mind:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf */
#include <ctype.h> /* for islower and the like */

void normalise_case(char str[], char result[])
{
    if (islower(str[0]))
    {
        result[0] = toupper(str[0]); /* capitalise at the start */
    }

    int i; /* older C standards (pre C99) won't like it if you don't pre-declare 'i' so I've put it here */

    for (i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        result[i] = str[i]; /* I've noticed that you copy the string in each if case, so I've put it here at the top */

        if (isupper(result[i]))
        {
            result[i] = tolower(result[i]);
        }

        if (result[i - 1] == ' ' && islower(result[i])) /* at the start of a word, capitalise! */
        {
            result[i] = toupper(result[i]);
        }

    }

    result[i] = '\0'; /* this has already been explained */
}

int main()
{
    char  in[20] = "tESt tHIs StrinG";

    char out[20] = ""; /* space to store the output */

    normalise_case(in, out);

    printf("%s\n", out); /* Prints 'Test This String' */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the little explanations on the side too! That really helps. :)

Comment: Glad you've found it useful, let me know if some line or other isn't clear. :)